# R count the number of rows as a combination

Tags: r

I have a dataset that looks like:
`order year  value

   1   1990      2

   1   1990      1

   1   1990      1

   2   1990      0

   3   1990      4

   1   1991      3

   2   1991      2

   2   1991      0`

I have been trying to get the count of the unique orders in particular year. I tried  `table(data$year)` which gives me:
`1990  1991

   5     3`

However, I would like to get:

`1990  1991

   3     2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do the trick. It uses `tapply()` to separately count the number of unique values of `order` for each level of `year`.

```
df <- read.table(text="order year value
1 1990 2
1 1990 1
1 1990 1
2 1990 0
3 1990 4
1 1991 3
2 1991 2
2 1991 0", header=T)

with(df, tapply(order, year, function(X) length(unique(X))))
# 1990 1991 
#    3    2
```

Answer (score 2):

Requisite plyr and data.table options:

```
dat <- read.table(text = txt, header = TRUE)

library(plyr)
ddply(dat, "year", summarize, val = length(unique(order)))

library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(dat)
dt[, length(unique(order)), by = year]
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done by calling `table` on the `unique` orders, instead of the detailed ones.

```
table( unique( df[,c("order","year")] )$year )
```